# Windows Driver keeps changing back no matter what

Tags: windows-10, drivers, video, device-manager, control-panel

On Windows 10, when I update a video driver, and then restart, it changes it back to the old driver. Why? How to force it to keep a specific video driver?

Comment: Provide more information about your `video driver` including it version, to make your post clearer, please.

Comment: If the video driver has been customized by the PC's OEM, it's the one that should be used, regardless if there are more up-to-date generic drivers available from the GPU's manufacturer, as PC OEM's usually customize the generic drivers to provide support for features custom to the PC, as using a generic driver in that scenario will remove the customizations made by the OEM _(for example, Intel's installer will often refuse to install generic drivers if it detects a hardware ID with OEM customized drivers, outputting a similar message)_

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Windows Updates will "update" newer driver you got from vendor to an older version in Microsoft's repository.

Instead of reinstalling the newer one again, try to revert the "update" in the device property.

Comment: If the video driver has been customized by the PC's OEM, it's the one that should be used, regardless if there are more up-to-date generic drivers available from the GPU's manufacturer, as PC OEM's usually customize the generic drivers to provide support for features custom to the PC, as using a generic driver in that scenario will remove the customizations made by the OEM

Comment: I beg to differ. Besides, the one on Microsoft is not necessarily OEM-specific either. Not to mention that how insane it is if a user needs to stick with such version when they often stop maintaining after a few months.

Comment: Specific to video drivers, if the PC OEM has customized the driver, that is the version Windows will almost always list through Windows Update, due to the fact PC OEM's often heavily customize the GPU drivers.